# How to display the user's already selected radio buttons after logging in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony2 and using fosuserbundle. 
I have created a small project using fosuserbundle which has a registration, login, 2 forms consisting of radio buttons to choose and submit after logging in or registering and a logout.
After a user logins and selects the various radio buttons and clicks on "Submit", he is taken to the "Success Page". But the next time again when the user logins, then the user's previously selected radio buttons are "NOT" shown, but the form with the default radio buttons checked are shown. I wanted to display the user's already selected radio buttons after the user logs in(if he has selected it earlier by logging in) or the default form(for a new user who has just now logged in and not selected any radio buttons earlier).

This is the "Subscriptions" entity:-

```
<?php

namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="subscriptions")
*/
class Subscriptions {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="Event1", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Events")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Event1", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/    
protected $event1;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="Event2", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Events")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Event2", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/

protected $event2;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="Event3", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Events")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Event3", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $event3;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Students")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
 protected $students;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set id
 *
 * @param integer $id
 * @return Subscriptions
 */
public function setId($id) 
{
    $this->id = $id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set event1
 *
 * @param integer $event1
 * @return Subscriptions
 */
public function setEvent1($event1)
{
    $this->event1 = $event1;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get event1
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getEvent1()
{
    return $this->event1;
}

/**
 * Set event2
 *
 * @param integer $event2
 * @return Subscriptions
 */
public function setEvent2($event2)
{
    $this->event2 = $event2;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get event2
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getEvent2()
{
    return $this->event2;
}

/**
 * Set event3
 *
 * @param integer $event3
 * @return Subscriptions
 */
public function setEvent3($event3)
{
    $this->event3 = $event3;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get event3
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getEvent3()
{
    return $this->event3;
}
}
```

Note:- There are 2 more entities namely :-
1. Students
2. Events.
But it is not so closely related to this problem, so to save space I have not mentioned it here. Anyways, the relationships between the various entities have been set properly

This is the "SubscriptionsType" :-

```
<?php

namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class SubscriptionsType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

->add('event1', 'choice', array('choices' => array('1' => 'Tourism', '2' => 'Food party',     '3'     => 'South korean food', '4' => 'Cooking', '5' => 'None of the above'), 'data' => '5', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))

->add('event2', 'choice', array('choices' => array('6' => 'Cricket', '7' => 'Football', '8' => 'Hockey', '9' => 'Baseball', '10' => 'Polo', '5' => 'None of the above'), 'data' => '5', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))

->add('event3', 'choice', array('choices' => array('11' => 'Game 1', '12' => 'Game 2', '13' => 'Game 3', '14' => 'Game 4', '15' => 'Game 5', '5' => 'None of the above'), 'data' => '5', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))

->add('register', 'submit');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'subscriptions';
}
}
```

This is the Controller (What code needs to be written in this Controller to solve the above problem ???) :-

```
namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity\Subscriptions;
use InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Form\Type\SubscriptionsType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

 /**
 * This action displays the form for the events of day 1.
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * @return A Confirmation page on success
 */
public function eventsoneAction(Request $request) {

    //Get current time and date

     date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
     $current_date = date('Y/m/d h:i:s a', time());

    //Set expiration date

    $deadline1 = $this->container->getParameter('deadline_day1');
    $date=date_create($deadline1,timezone_open("Europe/Paris"));

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $subscriptions = new Subscriptions();

    $form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType, new Subscriptions());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
    //Save to the Database    
    $subscriptions = $form->getData();

    $em->persist($subscriptions);
    $em->flush();

      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('institute_events_student_eventsregistered'));
    }

     if($current_date > date_format($date,"Y/m/d h:i:s a")) {
       return $this->render('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Default:registrationsclosed.html.twig');
       }
     else {
          $form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType, new Subscriptions());

          return $this->render('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Default:eventsday1.html.twig', array('form' => $form ->createView()));
     }
}

/**
 * This action displays the Confirmation page on success.
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * @return A Confirmation page on success
 */
public function eventsregisteredAction() {
    return $this->render('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Default:eventsregistered.html.twig');
}
```

}

In the below controller, I am trying to fetch the events(i.e event id) that the user has selected from the database and passing it to the "formtype" so that it uses these events(i.e event id) and displays the users original radio button selected form after logging in. But it throws an error. Can any1 help as to how to show the logged in user his/her selected values of the radio buttons ???

```
 <?php

namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity\Subscriptions;
use InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Form\Type\SubscriptionsType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

 /**
 * This action displays the form for the events of day 1.
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * @return A Confirmation page on success
 */
public function eventsoneAction(Request $request) {

    //Get current time and date

     date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
     $current_date = date('Y/m/d h:i:s a', time());

    //Set expiration date

    $deadline1 = $this->container->getParameter('deadline_day1');
    $date=date_create($deadline1,timezone_open("Europe/Paris"));

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $subscriptions = new Subscriptions();

    //Check if events already selected
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Subscriptions');

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
             ->select('p.event1','p.event2','p.event3','p.event4')
             ->where('p.id = p.getId()')
             ->getQuery();

    $subscriptionsreg = $query->getResult();

    $form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType($subscriptionsreg), new Subscriptions());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
    //Save to the Database    
    $subscriptions = $form->getData();

    $em->persist($subscriptions);
    $em->flush();

      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('institute_events_student_eventsregistered'));
    }

     if($current_date > date_format($date,"Y/m/d h:i:s a")) {
       return $this->render('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Default:registrationsclosed.html.twig');
       }
     else {
          $form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType, new Subscriptions());

          return $this->render('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Default:eventsday1.html.twig', array('form' => $form ->createView()));
     }
}

/**
 * This action displays the Confirmation page on success.
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * @return A Confirmation page on success
 */
public function eventsregisteredAction() {
    return $this->render('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Default:eventsregistered.html.twig');
}
```

}

Comment: Is it possible using "Event Listeners" ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are creating a new `Subscriptions` entity every time in the controller:

```
$subscriptions = new Subscriptions();
```

And you don't even use it in the `createForm`:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType, new Subscriptions());
```

Plus there's no point where the `Subscription` is associated with your user, who I'm assuming is a `Student` entity. To fix this, you must do something like:

```
if (!($subscriptions = $this->getUser()->getSubscriptions())) { // This line may not be right
    $subscriptions = new Subscriptions();
    $subscriptions->setStudents($this->getUser());
}

$form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType, $subscriptions);
```

I suspect that there are other "holes" in your development, so this won't be a complete solution to your issues, but it addresses the main point to your question.

The line that may not be right could also be something like:

```
if (!($subscriptions = $em->getRepository('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Subscriptions')->findBy(...))) {
```

Comment: Thank You sjagr. Can anyone suggest as to how to fetch the events(i.e event id) that the user has selected from the database and passing it to the "formtype" so that it uses these events(i.e event id) and displays the users original radio button selected form after logging in ?

Comment: @sachintendulkar No, not without full details of your application. A general strategy is to pass a parameter to the controller to fetch the object from the database. In terms of the scope of your original question here, it has been answered.