# Display the user's already selected radio buttons after logging in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony2. I have created a small project using fosuserbundle which has a registration, login, 2 forms consisting of radio buttons to choose and submit after logging in or registering and a logout.
I wanted the controller action code to display the user's already selected radio buttons in the form after the user logs in(if he has selected it earlier by logging in) or to display the default form which has default selected radio buttons(for a new user who has just now logged in and not selected any radio buttons earlier). The code of my project is very similar to the code on the link :- [How to display the user's already selected radio buttons after logging in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385344/how-to-display-the-users-already-selected-radio-buttons-after-logging-in-symfon)

The code is :-

This is the "Subscriptions" entity:-

```
<?php

namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="subscriptions")
*/
class Subscriptions {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 protected $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="Event1", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Events")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Event1", referencedColumnName="id")
**/    
protected $event1;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="Event2", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Events")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Event2", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/

protected $event2;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="Event3", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Events")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Event3", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $event3;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Students")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $students;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set id
 *
 * @param integer $id
 * @return Subscriptions
 */
public function setId($id) 
{
$this->id = $id;

return $this;
}

/**
 * Set event1
 *
 * @param integer $event1
 * @return Subscriptions
 */
public function setEvent1($event1)
{
$this->event1 = $event1;

return $this;
}

/**
 * Get event1
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getEvent1()
{
return $this->event1;
}

/**
 * Set event2
 *
 * @param integer $event2
 * @return Subscriptions
 */
public function setEvent2($event2)
{
$this->event2 = $event2;

return $this;
}

/**
 * Get event2
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getEvent2()
{
return $this->event2;
}

/**
 * Set event3
 *
 * @param integer $event3
 * @return Subscriptions
 */
public function setEvent3($event3)
{
$this->event3 = $event3;

return $this;
}

/**
 * Get event3
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getEvent3()
{
return $this->event3;
}
}
```

Note:- There are 2 more entities namely :- 1. Students 2. Events. But it is not so closely related to this problem, so to save space I have not mentioned it here. Anyways, the relationships between the various entities have been set properly

This is the "SubscriptionsType" :-

```
<?php

namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class SubscriptionsType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder


->add('event1', 'choice', array('choices' => array('1' => 'Tourism', '2' => 'Food party',     '3'     => 'South korean food', '4' => 'Cooking', '5' => 'None of the above'), 'data' => '5', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))

->add('event2', 'choice', array('choices' => array('6' => 'Cricket', '7' => 'Football', '8' => 'Hockey', '9' => 'Baseball', '10' => 'Polo', '5' => 'None of the above'), 'data' => '5', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))

->add('event3', 'choice', array('choices' => array('11' => 'Game 1', '12' => 'Game 2', '13' => 'Game 3', '14' => 'Game 4', '15' => 'Game 5', '5' => 'None of the above'), 'data' => '5', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false))

->add('register', 'submit');
}

public function getName()
{
return 'subscriptions';
}
}
```

In the below controller, I am trying to fetch the events(i.e event id) that the user has selected from the database and passing it to the "formtype" so that it uses these events(i.e event id) and displays the users original radio button selected form after logging in. But it throws an error. Can any1 help as to how to show the logged in user his/her selected values of the radio buttons ???

```
<?php

namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity\Subscriptions;
use InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Form\Type\SubscriptionsType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

 /**
  * This action displays the form for the events of day 1.
  * 
  * @param Request $request
  * @return A Confirmation page on success
 */
public function eventsoneAction(Request $request) {

 //Get current time and date

 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
 $current_date = date('Y/m/d h:i:s a', time());

//Set expiration date

$deadline1 = $this->container->getParameter('deadline_day1');
$date=date_create($deadline1,timezone_open("Europe/Paris"));

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$subscriptions = new Subscriptions();

//Check if events already selected
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Subscriptions');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
         ->select('p.event1','p.event2','p.event3','p.event4')
         ->where('p.id = p.getId()')
         ->getQuery();

$subscriptionsreg = $query->getResult();//This contains users selected radio buttons(if any) and this is being passed to the formtype "SubscriptionsType"

$form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType($subscriptionsreg), $subscriptions);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
//Save to the Database    
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$em->persist($subscriptions);
$em->flush();

  return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('institute_events_student_eventsregistered'));
}

 if($current_date > date_format($date,"Y/m/d h:i:s a")) {
   return $this->render('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Default:registrationsclosed.html.twig');
   }
 else {
      $form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionsType($subscriptionsreg), new Subscriptions());

      return $this->render('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Default:eventsday1.html.twig', array('form' => $form ->createView()));
 }
 }

/**
 * This action displays the Confirmation page on success.
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * @return A Confirmation page on success
 */
public function eventsregisteredAction() {
return $this->render('InstituteEventsStudentBundle:Default:eventsregistered.html.twig');
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a relation between subcriptions and users? Beucase you need it and i could not see any defining with the user entity on your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated Answer:

Note: I will use yml format to make doctrine mappings (i don't remember how to use annotations).

**Step 1:**

Creating Relational Tables

Events:

event.orm.yml

```
InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity\Event:
  type: entity
  table: events
  manyToMany:
    users:
      targetEntity: InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity\User
      mappedBy: events
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      length: 11
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    title:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: false
```

Users:

user.orm.yml

```
InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity\User:
  type:  entity
  table: users
  gedmo:
    soft_deleteable:
      field_name: deleted_at
  manyToMany:
    events:
      targetEntity: InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity\Event
      joinTable:
        name: user_event_selections
        joinColumns:
          user_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          event_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      length: 11
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    created_at:
      type: datetime
      nullable: false
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: create
    updated_at:
      type: datetime
      nullable: true
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: update
    deleted_at:
      type: datetime
      nullable: true
```

**Step 2:**

Creating the form:

```
<?php

namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('events', 'entity', array('label' => 'Selections', 'class' => 'InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity\Event', 'property' => 'title', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**

Controller

```
<?php

// codes...

public function profileAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}


// send this to your view.
$form_view = $form->createView();
```

**Step 4:**

View:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

---

Okay, these example show you how to set and get the user selections automatically on form submit. You don't have to make any entity save.

Comment: Hey, R. Canser Yanbakan I have posted my code above.

Comment: The relationships between all the entities has been established.I used annotations. I wanted the code for the controller action so that if a user has already checked the radio buttons, and if the same user logs in again then the radio buttons which he had previously checked should be shown. Else if the user is logged in without selecting the radio buttons then he should be shown the "Default form" which has "Default" radio buttons selected ->This I did in "SubscriptionsType" by using "'data' => '5" so that always None of the above option is checked as "Default" radio button)

Comment: Look the basic idea is, user entity must be the key in here. What do you want to do with that selections? Show them in a form? Use them in a controller? Because if you have already did a relation between the user and the selections, you can get the selections as easily like this: $user->getSelection(). You don't have to use query builder for that.

Comment: Yes, I need the selections of the user and show them in the same form in which they had made these selections, the next time they login. So for that reason I am retrieving those selections from the database as I save the user selections in the database and pass them into the formtype for that particular user.This passing of the selected values to the formtype I am unable to do.

Comment: Something like a "Sticky form" for the user who logs in and if he has selected some radio buttons earlier, else show him the default form with the default radio buttons selected

Comment: Made a complete solution.

Comment: Let me know if you need help. No problem.

Comment: Sure, Thanks once again